# Google Cloud Free Trail confuse me a lot, am I going to pay automatically or not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Thing is that I have just activated a google cloud free trail, and it says everywhere that I am not going to pay anything even if the trail ends, unless I explicitly update my account to a paid one. But when I go to billing configuration it says that I am going to pay the first day of the month or before if I surpass a certain threshold. I still have 90 days of the free trail, but now my question is.

Am I going to pay automatically once these 90 days passes? What can you tell me in your experience. Thank you very much.

Comment: Review the terms of the free trial. If you do not post a credit card, then you will not be able to use some services but their is no risk of being charged. If you do convert to a paid account, you have a $300 credit. After you consume the credit or the time expires you will be charged. https://cloud.google.com/free

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it is not related to coding but customer support question.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be charged anything until you explicitly convert your account to paid account. You will not be charged after 90 days, just your services will terminate.